# In Laravel 7.x how to identify if the mail was triggered using the Mail::send() or the Mail::queue()

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have a code like below in Laravel7.x

```
Mail::queue(new ReportMail($user));
Mail::send(new ReportMail($user));
```

In the ReportMail Class is there a way to know if the mail was called by the
Mail::send() or Mail::queue() ?

All my mail MailClasses pass through a MailTrait function before the mail is being send.

In there i use a throttle function as below:

```
// somewhere in the file - app/Traits/MailTrait.php
Redis::throttle('emails')
    ->allow(300)    // Maximum number of allowed operations
    ->every(60)     // Time period in seconds for the rate limit
    ->block(60)     // Blocking time (seconds) if rate limit is exceeded
    ->then(
    function () use ($mailTemplateObj) {
        $this->sendFinalizedMail($mailTemplateObj);
    },
    function () {
        Log::info('Throttling, Too many email requests received!');
    }
);
```

This works well with the queued mails...But when send mail is triggered while the queue is still in process. Somehow this breaks the queue and a restart is required.

So i need to figure out in the MailClass in our eg: In the ReportMail, if the mail is a send() or queue() and avoid the redis::throttle() for mail::send()

I can fix this by adding a flag to ReportMail Class, But the problem is I have about
300 such MailClasses and i need to implement in each of them, which feels not a good way to fix this...

Any good ideas from u guys greatly appreciated...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this without modifying each MailClass individually, you can leverage the Laravel event system to set a flag when the mail is sent through the queue.
Create a custom event class

```
    // app/Events/MailSentEvent.php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MailSentEvent
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $isQueued;

    public function __construct($isQueued)
    {
        $this->isQueued = $isQueued;
    }
}
```

Modify your MailTrait to dispatch the event when the mail is sent

```
// app/Traits/MailTrait.php

use App\Events\MailSentEvent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

// ...

public function sendFinalizedMail($mailTemplateObj, $isQueued = false)
{
    Redis::throttle('emails')
        ->allow(300)
        ->every(60)
        ->block(60)
        ->then(
            function () use ($mailTemplateObj, $isQueued) {
                $this->sendFinalizedMail($mailTemplateObj);
                Event::dispatch(new MailSentEvent($isQueued));
            },
            function () {
                Log::info('Throttling, Too many email requests received!');
            }
        );
}
```

In your ReportMail class, check the flag before applying the throttle

```
// app/Mail/ReportMail.php

use App\Events\MailSentEvent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;

class ReportMail extends Mailable
{
    public function build()
    {
        // ...

        $isQueued = Event::hasListeners(MailSentEvent::class);

        // Use $isQueued to determine if the mail is sent through queue or not
        if (!$isQueued) {
            Redis::throttle('emails')
                ->allow(300)
                ->every(60)
                ->block(60)
                ->then(
                    function () {
                        $this->sendFinalizedMail($mailTemplateObj);
                    },
                    function () {
                        Log::info('Throttling, Too many email requests received!');
                    }
                );
        } else {
            $this->sendFinalizedMail($mailTemplateObj, true);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can centralize the logic in the MailTrait and use the event system to set the flag dynamically. This reduces the need to modify each MailClass individually.